# Кодировка текста из переменной

Tags: php, кодировка

Пытаюсь вывести в html кнопки с текстом вот таким php-скриптом:

```
$tags;

switch (basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])){
    case "333.php":
    $tags = <<<EOT
    <a href="https://site.ru/page1.html"><button>Первая страница</button></a>
<a href="https://site.ru/page2.html"><button>Вторая страница</button></a>
<a href="https://site.ru/page3.html"><button>Третья страница</button></a>
<a href="https://site.ru/page4.html"><button>Четвертая страница</button></a>
EOT;
$convertedTags = mb_convert_variables($tags, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($tags));
break;
}
```

Кнопки выводятся, но вместо кириллицы на кнопках только знаки вопроса.
Я пробовала также:

```
$convertedTags = mb_convert_encoding($tags,'utf-8',mb_detect_encoding($tags));
```

Или так:`$convertedTags = mb_convert_encoding($tags,'utf-8');`

Но в этих случаях вообще кнопки/ссылки не отображаются.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перевести на русский текст на кнопках.

Спасибо!

Comment: может все из-за того что вы сначала конвертируйте не пойми что а потом той самой переменной присваиваете обычный текст?

Comment: Я пробовала по-разному. И в case писать $convertedTags = mb_convert_variables($tags, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($tags));

Comment: Честно говоря я уже давно не слышал про проблемы с кодировкой, вроде бы этого зверя давно победили. Надо больше деталей. Возможно проблема не в скрипте а допустим у настройках сервера или на самой машине где запускается код.

Comment: Код запускается на сервере у хостера.

Comment: https://school-php.com/tricks/18/vyistavlyaem-kodirovku-utf-8 мне лично помогла эта статья. Попробуйте выполнить советы с нее, если не поможет то будем думать о других вариантах

Comment: Arendach, да! Вы правы. Открыла в notepad ++ и пересохранила в кодировке utf-8 без BOM. И все стало отображаться по-русски. Спасибо!!! Оформите свой комментарий ответом, чтобы я могла выбрать его лучшим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При сохранении файлов (обязательно ВСЕХ!) выбрать кодировку UTF-8 without BOM, повторюсь, without BOM - это необходимая настройка, в противном случае Ваш сайт не будет работать как надо.

Источник [Выставляем кодировку UTF-8](https://school-php.com/tricks/18/vyistavlyaem-kodirovku-utf-8)